# How to set max length to android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an editbox and it max length set to 6 digit. it works clearly, but on the keyboard i can continue typing.

edittext : 111111

keyboard : 11111111111111111 ....

and when try to delete, it deletes the number from right to left, when keyboard comes to 6. digit, i can delete edittext.

Do you have any experience on it ?

i cant upload image from work,

```
------------------
-111111          -  - edittext max length 6 
------------------




-------------------
- 1111111111...   - -> recommendation textbox on native keyboard
-------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
q w e ....
..
..
..
..
-------------------



    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextSMSPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            style="@style/EditboxStandart"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:hint="Cep Şifre" />




   <style name="EditboxStandart">
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/editbox_standart_height</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/editbox_standart_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_rounded_text</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on the keyboard"?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `android:maxLength="6"` on that `EditText`?

Comment: you can look at the edited question, i cant upload image from work so i try to draw.

Comment: Hmm.. `android:maxLength="6"` should restrict typing more than 6 characters. Try removing the custom style, maybe that's causing the side effect?

Answer (score -1):

`android:maxLength="6"` should work, but since it isn't it might be happening because of your new style, so use an input filter to limit the max length of a text view.

```
TextView editEntryVew = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```